# Terraform Error: Error initializing Docker client: protocol not available

Tags: docker, terraform

I am attempting to go through the Terraform install from their website at https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/azure/install
When I get to the step that says to run `terraform apply` I get the following error:

```
Error: Error initializing Docker client: protocol not available

  on <empty> line 0:
  (source code not available)
```

I am not sure what to do, any suggestions?  I am running this on a Windows 10 Pro machine.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I found an answer that works.  I am not sure what it means, but it did solve my problem.  According to an issue posted on github at https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-docker/issues/180 I added the following to my main.tf file:

```
provider "docker" {
  version = "~> 2.7"
  host    = "npipe:////.//pipe//docker_engine"
}
```

This allowed me to run the command `terraform apply` successfully.  If anyone can explain the details of this, I'd appreciate it.  I really don't fully grasp the host setting.  But, it works.